# How to calculate average velocity for different acceleration?

Tags: gps, velocity, acceleration

I want to calculate average speed of the distance traveled using gps signals.

Is this formula calculates correct avg speed?

`avgspeed = totalspeed/count`

where count is the no.of gps signals.

If it is wrong,please any one tell me the correct formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that should work, remember that GPS signals can be confused easily if you're in diverse terrain. Therefore, I would not use an arithmetic mean, but compute the median, so outliers (quick jumps) would not have such a big effect on the result.

From Wikipedia (n being the number of signals):

> If n is odd then Median (M) = value of ((n + 1)/2)th item term.
>
> If n is even then Median (M) = value of [((n)/2)th item term + ((n)/2
>   + 1)th item term ]/2